# database in drupal 7

Tags: database, drupal, drupal-7

when i installing drupal 7 ".ht.sqlite" its create a file like this so if i want to move the site ,how can i import the database

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get the question. If you have a file like that, it means that you have chosen sqlite as the database backend. This means that this file *is* the database.

If you want to move your site around, just move that file too. You can also move it to a different place, you just need to update the path to it in your sites/default/settings.php file.

Comment: no i mean when istalling in WAMP server sites\default\files\ht.sqlite

Comment: Yes, but what exactly is your question? Again, as you seem to have chosen sqlite, that file (and only that file) is your database. Where do you want to move it to? Into a Mysql database? I don't think that will work, you need to install to MySQL locally too to be able to move it around.